# How to install my NativeScript application in my phone?

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I have build an android application using NativeScript but now i want to install it in my android phone but i don't know which .apk file i have to take to install the application in my phone.

Comment: my application works in the emulator but it's just that i don't know which file i have to take to install it on my phone i'm searching the solution on internet ...

Comment: I have find out that : When you build for Android, the NativeScript CLI saves the application package as an APK in platforms → android → bin. But there is 2 .apk file i will try the both ...

Comment: What IDE are you using? Android Studio? You can see in the console which apk is being used. Also you can use usb debugging on your smartphone so you can directly test your app.

Comment: i'm using sublime text, it's was a good idea to see the console, my application is called "newapp" (it's a test project ...), so in the console i find out that in the data/app folder there is a file called "org.nativescript.newapp-1.apk" it might the good one, i will test it out tomorrow to see if it work thanks for your help. (sorry for my english errors it's not my native language.)

Answer (score 4):

According to the {N} docs you should execute **tns deploy android** on the command line. This will install your app onto the currently connected device. After the app has been installed, it will automatically start on Android.

If you want your app to be compiled before installing it on your device, you should execute **tns run android** on the command line. This will prepare, build and deploy your app.

You can find all the cli commands on the github page: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli

Comment: Yes i used to use this way but with the emulator but i found the solution thanks.

Comment: Could you post your solution here as a reference for others running into this issue?

Comment: I just take the yourapplicationame-debug.apk file in the platforms/android/bin directory and copy it to the download folder in my phone and installed it. My application works with ARC Welder too. All is perfect.

Comment: @EmmaLat I think you don't have the ADB driver from your device correctly installed in your computer. Once you have it, the command `tns run android` will work perfectly and you will have debug logs in your console (which you don't actually have copying the .apk to the device storage